# How to use C++11 in Qt creator 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, qt-creator

I have looked everywhere and the [solution](https://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html) to this is to add a line of code to a '.pro' file in my project. I cannot see any such files though! I can see a *qbs* file, the *main.cpp* file and a *xcode.qbs* file.

This is how I started: using a Mac, I installed Qt Creator 4.8 (Clang v5.12) and I created a 'plain C++ project' which uses Qmake.

I am using the {} to initialise a variable but it won't allow me to. I had a similar problem with Eclipse and found a solution. Any help, please?

This is the code I am testing:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   int a{5};
   std::cout << a;
   return 0;
  }
```

The error code for the line where I define *a* is:
"/Users/xxxxxx/Coding/HelloEarth/main.cpp:5: error: expected ';' at end of declaration"

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you've created a qbs project. Have you tried changing https://doc.qt.io/qbs/qml-qbsmodules-cpp.html#cxxLanguageVersion-prop ? Though your error is still strange, since Clang should have C++11/14 as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest approach to creating a qt project:

1. Open a new terminal and create an empty folder `Foo/` in your Desktop: `~$ cd Desktop; mkdir Foo/`
2. Change to that folder: `~$ cd ~/Desktop/Foo`
3. Create 2 files: `~$ touch Foo.pro main.cpp`
4. If you have exported the correct paths in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, then you can type `~$ qtcreator` in your terminal to run qt. Otherwise, click on the QtCreator App from the applications.
5. Go to `File -> Open project` and select the `Foo.pro` file.
6. Keep the default paths to debug and release mode, and hit continue, or ok (can't remember exactly)
7. You should have the `Foo.pro` file open in Qt. Now enter the following lines in the Foo.pro file and hit save (Ctrl+S).

> ```
> CONFIG  +=  c++11 console
> TARGET  =  My_Foo
> SOURCES +=  main.cpp
> ```

8. Once you hit save, you should see the main.cpp file on the left pane that lists the project files. If so, click on the Projects button (spanner tool) on the left menu.
9. Under the `Build option`, untick `shadow build` and under the `Run option`, untick `Run in terminal`.
10. Go back to your main.cpp file and type a simple hello program. Press `Ctr+S` (to save), `Ctrl+B` (to build the project) and `Ctrl+R` (to run).

Up until step 7, you can do it using the GUI, by selecting Create new Project and then select console application. Btw, on mac use Cmd instead of Ctrl.

Also make sure you have the correct compilers setup. (https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html)